# Coverage with Emma in Android project

Tags: java, android, code-coverage, emma

I have a android project in which I create a folder for tests.
My test pass with success xith JUnit but when I want see the coverage with Emma I found a error.
I have install Emma pluging with help> Install New Software and the green icon is appear.

I structure my project like this :

- MyApp

  - src

    - com.example.orga

      - LoginActivity.java
  - res
  - tests

    - com.example.orga.test

      - R.java
      - BuildConfif.java
    - AndroidTestTest.src.com.example.orga.test

      - LoginActivityTest.java

See my LoginActivityTest.java

```
public class LoginActivityTest extends
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {


    private LoginActivity mActivity;
    private EditText ed_username;

    public LoginActivityTest() {
        super(LoginActivity.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
       super.setUp();

        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

       mActivity = getActivity();

       ed_username =(EditText)     mActivity.findViewById(com.example.organisateur.R.id.editTextMail);

    } // end of setUp() method definition


   public void testFillUsername(){
        // set text
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            ed_username.setText("paul");
          }
        });

        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        assertEquals("Text incorrect", "paul", ed_username.getText().toString());

    }
 }
```

In the AndroidManifest.XML File

```
  <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="com.example.organisateur"
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

...

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```

The error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 at      
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) 
.... 
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 at    
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong with my project ?

Comment: I just forget to show error !
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
....
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Do you have a custom ActivityUnitTestCase2 class extends to test case? As far as I know, the class is called ActivityUnitTestCase.

Comment: I use the extends ActivityUnitTestCase but I found the same error.

Comment: Ok, I found why I had this error.I have to include JUnit.jar in my project  additionally to install pluging  JUnit using Eclipse tools.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found why I had this error.I have to include JUnit.jar in my project additionally to install pluging JUnit using Eclipse tools.